# listBox selectedItem issue

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

This works fine:

```
private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.SelectedItems.Count; i++) 
    {
        listBox1.Items.Remove(listBox1.SelectedItems[i].ToString());
        i--;
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work:

```
private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox1.Items.Remove(listBox1.SelectedItems);
}
```

Why is the second `btnDelete_Click` not working? I mean I select a line on my `listBox1` with my mouse and then press the button. 
Doesn't the `.Remove` function recognize which line I selected? Even though I say `.Remove(listBox1.SelectedItem)`, is it a must to have and selectedItem array? Isn't the word `SelectedItems` self-explanatory? And since I clicked the line on my `listBox1` with my mouse, can't the program or the IDE understand which line is selected? Why do I still have to use `SelectedItems[i]`?

Comment: Out of interest, why are you calling `ToString()` on the first one? Remove method takes type `object`.

Comment: and why are you doing i--, your looping through all items and yr locking the loop remove the i--;   or explain to me why you did that, see my answers

Comment: yes Bali C ur right no need the ToString()

Comment: @JohnnBlade It must be because when the item is removed the index of the remaining items will be shifted down one. I guess you can add it there if you want it :)

Comment: Bali C don't we need to i-- ? i think we need but İ cannot explain. and john ask why we need to do that way? can u explain Bali C

Comment: you have to loop backwards to remove items from the collection

Comment: @modestandcutegirl I think you are right, yes. In that particular loop you will need `i--`, as the indexes of the selected items will change everytime one is removed.

Comment: thanks Bali C so John u got it from Bali C's explanation? i know he is an legend so i passed ur question to him :)

Comment: I got the answer from myself, but that loop of yours it might work but is wrong aka bad practice

Comment: ok john since i'm not an expert i may not say much.

Comment: Tell @Bali C, he should loop backwards, and not use i--;

Comment: @modestandcutegirl Haha :) Your loop is fine, although I wouldn't personally do it that way. Check my answer, for a quick explanation and personally prefered alternative.

Comment: ok :) i think he sees ur writing and can think about it. but actually im with Bali C. so if u explain why its a bad practice i will be happy. ur welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the second example does not work is because you are trying to pass multiple items in the form of a collection to be removed at once.

To remove an item you need to do it one at a time, hence why you ***need*** a loop.

Also, might I suggest using a `ListView` instead? I personally find them easier to use with many more options.

For example you could make your loop for a `ListView` with just this

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.SelectedItems)
{
    item.Remove();
}
```

If you are trying to remove only one item at a time that is selected then you do

```
listBox1.Items.Remove(listBox1.SelectedItem);
```

`SelectedItem` rather than `SelectedItems`, plural being the collection that it can't handle without a loop, singular being a single item that it can understand.

Comment: ok Bali C thanks for the ListView stuff. it seems more easy as u pointed. and about the reason u gave i am not selecting multiple lines. and i didn't opened that property i can select only one line not multiple and i one to remove only one item. not multiple item. sorry if i understand u wrong. do u have a saying or explain in more deep. thanks.

Comment: Ok, see my answer now, hopefully that answers your question, if I understand :)

Comment: thanks Bali C now its clear and i want to thank you all in here who joined my question and enlighten.

Comment: I thought you must have meant that :)

Answer (score 1):

I think SelectedItems needs indeks number.
Maybe that's why you can't delete any item.

Comment: yes as i understood from the experience it needs index number but why? im selecting the line and and i use .Remove cant the program or IDE understand that? why i need to give index number? thats the question!!!

Answer (score 1):

`listBox1.SelectedItems` returns a collection of selected items.  To remove an item, you can only pass in a single object in collection, using `Remove()`, OR an index to an object in the collection with `RemoveAt()`.

Remove an object:

```
listBox1.Items.Remove(listBox1.SelectedItem);
```

Remove an object at index:

```
listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(5);
```

There is no RemoveRange() method, which is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

also change

```
for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.SelectedItems.Count; i++) 
{
    listBox1.Items.Remove(listBox1.SelectedItems[i].ToString());
    i--;
}
```

to

```
    for (int i = (listBox1.SelectedItems.Count - 1); i >= 0; i--)
    { 
      listBox1.Items.Remove(listBox1.SelectedItems[i]);
    }
```

and this should be

```
 listBox1.Items.Remove(listBox1.SelectedItem);
```

Comment: u read the question? i already know which one is working john and im not looking for the correction? i already experienced that i need to give and index number but why? i explained my question. can u please read it again and enlighten me thanks.

Comment: why did you add i--; its not needed unless you want the loop to be stuck at index 0

Comment: can u explain why its a weird practice or wrong aka as u said bad practice? if u enlighten i will be happy. thanks.

Comment: here is enough info for you to make up yr mind http://stackoverflow.com/questions/207038/best-way-to-remove-items-from-a-collection

Answer (score 1):

`ListBox.Items.Remove()` expects ***one single item*** to remove while `ListBox.SelectedItems` returns a ***collection of items*** (`SelectedObjectCollection`) - even if only one item is selected!

You could write an extension method for removing all selected items:

```
public static class ListBoxExtension
{
    public static void RemoveSelectedItems(this ListBox source)
    {
        if(source==null) return;
        while(source.SelectedItems.Count!=0)
        {
            source.Items.Remove(source.SelectedItems[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

This can be used like that:

```
this.listbox1.RemoveSelectedItems();
```

Comment: i tried  this.listBox1.RemoveSelectedItems();  but its not working. after  this.listBox1. there is no such thing like RemoveSelectedItems()

Comment: Yes, that's why you need to define the extension method.

Comment: there is, its an extension method, copy all into an new class, and then you will see an extension method added to your listbox

Comment: yes ok John ur right i missed. actually lost in all conversations. my head started to turn :)

Comment: Now give all of us some votes and points for talking sooo long to you :)

Comment: sure i already did john. i'm happy to be in such a great platform with great people. i really appreciate and respect all your knowledge.