# Is it possible to implement RemoveAll() on EntityCollection<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

I have a question similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207038/best-way-to-remove-items-from-a-collection), but pertaining to `EntityCollection<>`.

`EntityCollection` implements `Remove()`, allowing you to remove a *single* item from the list at once.  However, I'd like to implement an extension method that can remove multiple items at once, similar to `IList<T>`'s `RemoveAll(Predicate<T> match)` method.

One idea would be to loop through the list, and remove items.  Something like:

```
public static void RemoveAll<T>(this EntityCollection<T> collection, Predicate<T> match) where T : EntityObject
{
   foreach (T o in collection)
   {
      if (match(o))
         collection.Remove(o);
   }
}
```

However, this will throw an exception because you can't modify the collection you're iterating through.

Another idea would be to build a temporary list of items to remove, then loop through *that* list and remove each item from the collection.  However, this seems inefficient to me.  Is there a better implementation?

Comment: Not sure on the inefficiency, but I'm afraid iterating over a secondary list is the only safe choice here. In terms of implementation, with LINQ you can get something quite short.

Comment: Yeah I'm thinking you're right..

Comment: Pity that MS didn't add `RemoveWhere` to the `ICollection<T>` interface.

Comment: @CodesInChaos, adding that requirement to `ICollection<T>` was probably not worth it (since the workaround is short enough) and would arguably push unnecessary effort to the implementor (most of the time). Note that none of the methods currently required to implement `ICollection<T>` take predicates or delegates in general.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I don't think that there is a good work around. The implementation strategy depends on the collection. An implementation of `RemoveWhere` needs to be completely different for `HashSet<T>`, `List<T>`, `LinkedList<T>`,...

Comment: @CodesInChaos, yes, we agree here, I was only saying putting such a member in the `ICollection<T>` *interface* resulted in additional burden for implementors. Of course, implementors are free to choose the best strategy for their own container semantics, but they should not be *required* to implement `RemoveWhere()`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As I said in comments, iterating over a secondary list is probably the only safe choice here.

You can implement it with something like:

```
public static void RemoveAll<T>(this EntityCollection<T> collection,
    Predicate<T> match) where T : EntityObject
{
    if (match == null) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("match");
    }

    collection.Where(entity => match(entity))
              .ToList().ForEach(entity => collection.Remove(entity));
}
```

Comment: Oh this is way better than my implementation.  `+1`

Comment: Keep in mind that this runs in O(n*(n+1)): ToList(n) + ForEach(n) * Remove(n); while the List's RemoveAll runs in O(n).
It can also be optimized a bit to at least run in O(n^2) by using: foreach(T entity in collection.Where(entity => match(entity))) { collection.Remove(entity); }