# Trouble removing items in arraylist

Tags: c#, file-io

Case:

I'm adding objects to my arraylist, before i add the object to my arraylist i check if the same does not exist already. After that I try to rewrite the complete arraylist to the text file.

Code:

```
WaardeObjecten obj = new WaardeObjecten(index.ToString(), allFiles[index].ToString(), values[0], values[1], values[2], values[3], values[4], values[5], values[6], values[7], values[8], values[9], values[10], values[11], values[12], values[13], values[14], values[15], values[16], values[17]);    

//Check if duplcatie
foreach (WaardeObjecten item in listOfWaardeObjecten)
{
      if (item.getIndex() == obj.getIndex())
      {
               listOfWaardeObjecten.Remove(item);
      }
}

//Add to arraylist
listOfWaardeObjecten.Add(obj);

//writedata to log file
writeLogFile();
```

Code for writing all arraylist elements to .txt file:

```
//Creating a streamwriter to write to the file with the path of logFileName.
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(logFileName, FileMode.Truncate, FileAccess.Write))
using (var sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
{
      foreach (WaardeObjecten item in listOfWaardeObjecten)
      {
           sw.WriteLine(item.getTotalString());
      }
}
```

Now I'm getting the following error:

> "An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll."
>
> "Additional Information: The collection has been changed. The inventory operation may not be performed."

**UPDATE**

The code im using now to remove duplicates:

```
//Check if duplcatie
for (int i = listOfWaardeObjecten.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
     if (i == obj.getIndex())
     {
           listOfWaardeObjecten.RemoveAt(i);
     }
}

//Add to arraylist
listOfWaardeObjecten.Add(obj);

//writedata to log file
writeLogFile();
```

Code im using to write textfile:

```
//Creating a streamwriter to write to the file with the path of logFileName.
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(logFileName, FileMode.Truncate, FileAccess.Write))
using (var sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
{
     foreach (WaardeObjecten item in listOfWaardeObjecten)
     {
          sw.WriteLine(item.getTotalString());
     }
}
```

Output if i first do 10-15 images with all different values and i rewind to the first image and put all values on "N.v.t.":

```
 2. C:\Users\Gebruiker\Desktop\MCA JPG2\05_Mechanical\01_Equipment\1100-final\A-1101-OSBL\99_History\fotos\A 1101 laadarm04.JPG : Discipline: Preset1 | Soort: Preset1 | Afdruk: Preset1 | Test1: Preset1 | Test2: Preset1 | Test3: Preset1 | Test4: Preset1 | Test5: Preset1 | Test6: Preset1.
 4. C:\Users\Gebruiker\Desktop\MCA JPG2\05_Mechanical\01_Equipment\1100-final\A-1101-OSBL\99_History\fotos\A 1101 laadarm06.JPG : Discipline: Preset1 | Soort: Preset1 | Afdruk: Preset1 | Test1: Preset1 | Test2: Preset1 | Test3: Preset1 | Test4: Preset1 | Test5: Preset1 | Test6: Preset1.
 6. C:\Users\Gebruiker\Desktop\MCA JPG2\05_Mechanical\01_Equipment\1100-final\A-1101-OSBL\99_History\fotos\A 1101 laadarm08.JPG : Discipline: Preset1 | Soort: Preset1 | Afdruk: Preset1 | Test1: Preset1 | Test2: Preset1 | Test3: Preset1 | Test4: Preset1 | Test5: Preset1 | Test6: Preset1.
 8. C:\Users\Gebruiker\Desktop\MCA JPG2\05_Mechanical\01_Equipment\1100-final\A-1101-OSBL\99_History\fotos\Detail tbv blisemafleiding A-1101.jpg : Discipline: Preset1 | Soort: Preset1 | Afdruk: Preset1 | Test1: Preset1 | Test2: Preset1 | Test3: Preset1 | Test4: Preset1 | Test5: Preset1 | Test6: Preset1.
 10. C:\Users\Gebruiker\Desktop\MCA JPG2\05_Mechanical\01_Equipment\1100-final\A-1101-OSBL\99_History\fotos\IMG-20131108-01010.jpg : Discipline: Preset1 | Soort: Preset1 | Afdruk: Preset1 | Test1: Preset1 | Test2: Preset1 | Test3: Preset1 | Test4: Preset1 | Test5: Preset1 | Test6: Preset1.
 1. C:\Users\Gebruiker\Desktop\MCA JPG2\05_Mechanical\01_Equipment\1100-final\A-1101-OSBL\99_History\fotos\A 1101 laadarm02.JPG : Discipline: N.v.t. | Soort: N.v.t. | Afdruk: N.v.t. | Test1: N.v.t. | Test2: N.v.t. | Test3: N.v.t. | Test4: N.v.t. | Test5: N.v.t. | Test6: N.v.t..
  3. C:\Users\Gebruiker\Desktop\MCA JPG2\05_Mechanical\01_Equipment\1100-final\A-1101-OSBL\99_History\fotos\A 1101 laadarm05.JPG : Discipline: N.v.t. | Soort: N.v.t. | Afdruk: N.v.t. | Test1: N.v.t. | Test2: N.v.t. | Test3: N.v.t. | Test4: N.v.t. | Test5: N.v.t. | Test6: N.v.t..
  5. C:\Users\Gebruiker\Desktop\MCA JPG2\05_Mechanical\01_Equipment\1100-final\A-1101-OSBL\99_History\fotos\A 1101 laadarm07.JPG : Discipline: N.v.t. | Soort: N.v.t. | Afdruk: N.v.t. | Test1: N.v.t. | Test2: N.v.t. | Test3: N.v.t. | Test4: N.v.t. | Test5: N.v.t. | Test6: N.v.t..
  7. C:\Users\Gebruiker\Desktop\MCA JPG2\05_Mechanical\01_Equipment\1100-final\A-1101-OSBL\99_History\fotos\beschadigde isolatie.jpg : Discipline: N.v.t. | Soort: N.v.t. | Afdruk: N.v.t. | Test1: N.v.t. | Test2: N.v.t. | Test3: N.v.t. | Test4: N.v.t. | Test5: N.v.t. | Test6: N.v.t..
  9. C:\Users\Gebruiker\Desktop\MCA JPG2\05_Mechanical\01_Equipment\1100-final\A-1101-OSBL\99_History\fotos\Foto tbv bliksemafleiding 1.jpg : Discipline: N.v.t. | Soort: N.v.t. | Afdruk: N.v.t. | Test1: N.v.t. | Test2: N.v.t. | Test3: N.v.t. | Test4: N.v.t. | Test5: N.v.t. | Test6: N.v.t..
  11. C:\Users\Gebruiker\Desktop\MCA JPG2\05_Mechanical\01_Equipment\1100-final\C-1106-final\99_History\Inspecties\DSC00864.JPG : Discipline: N.v.t. | Soort: N.v.t. | Afdruk: N.v.t. | Test1: N.v.t. | Test2: N.v.t. | Test3: N.v.t. | Test4: N.v.t. | Test5: N.v.t. | Test6: N.v.t..
  12. C:\Users\Gebruiker\Desktop\MCA JPG2\05_Mechanical\01_Equipment\1100-final\C-1107-fnal\99_History\Inspecties\DSC00864.JPG : Discipline: N.v.t. | Soort: N.v.t. | Afdruk: N.v.t. | Test1: N.v.t. | Test2: N.v.t. | Test3: N.v.t. | Test4: N.v.t. | Test5: N.v.t. | Test6: N.v.t..
  13. C:\Users\Gebruiker\Desktop\MCA JPG2\05_Mechanical\01_Equipment\1100-final\H-1104-final\99_History\Inspecties\100_0671.JPG : Discipline: N.v.t. | Soort: N.v.t. | Afdruk: N.v.t. | Test1: N.v.t. | Test2: N.v.t. | Test3: N.v.t. | Test4: N.v.t. | Test5: N.v.t. | Test6: N.v.t..
  14. C:\Users\Gebruiker\Desktop\MCA JPG2\05_Mechanical\01_Equipment\1100-final\P-1111-final\99_History\Onderhouds rapportages\2014 wk50  div schades\P-1111 eerste schadepomp  2.JPG : Discipline: N.v.t. | Soort: N.v.t. | Afdruk: N.v.t. | Test1: N.v.t. | Test2: N.v.t. | Test3: N.v.t. | Test4: N.v.t. | Test5: N.v.t. | Test6: N.v.t..
```

As you can see not all the values are updates to "N.v.t.".

Hope anyone can help!

Comment: You can't modify a collection that you're iterating over with `foreach`. Try a `for` loop and iterate backwards.

Comment: So i have to use a for loop instead of for each? and remove at (i)? How do i call the getIndex() function of that object aswell?

Comment: Yes, that should work, and start at the end and work backwards with `i--`.

Comment: example: listOfWaardeObjecten[2].getIndex() is not working?

Comment: listOfWaarObjecten[2] returns a WaardeObject, which has no knowledge of it's index. It really shouldn't be necessary, since you already know that the index (`i`) is 2.

Comment: Note that you shouldnt use an `ArrayList` anymore. `ArrayList´s` origin comes from a time where a `List` did not exist. So try to stick for basic stuff with an `Array` or extend your functionality with a `List`.

Comment: If you can change to using a `List<>` then you can do this: `listOfWaardeObjecten.RemoveAll(item => item.getIndex() == obj.getIndex());`

Comment: This worked! Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You can not modify/ remove item from collection when using `foreach` loop on collections. But if you want to remove item from collection then use `for` loop instead.

```
for (int i = listOfWaardeObjecten.Count-1; i >= 0; i--)
{
   if (i == obj.getIndex())
      {
         listOfWaardeObjecten.RemoveAt(i);
      }
}
```

In case if you don't want to use for loop then, you can use `break` statement with `foreach` loop. [**See here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/207048/2465787).

Comment: As stated by Equalsk above, you will need to iterate counting down over the collection, since the index numbers will change after a deletion. So use `for (int i = lostOfWaardeObjecten.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) { ... }`

Comment: For some reason the code seems fine but its not working in my program yet, can i update the post? or do i need to make a new one? Cant see why it is not working.

Comment: I've tried 5 images, and with all 5 images(duplicates) it went into the IF-condition.

Comment: It says i can  not use .Where in an arraylist.

Comment: I can switch it up so list, however i never used list, give me a second.

Comment: So which one i have to add to the list? obj or uniqueItems?

Comment: @Niels : Just do these steps nothing else.  `var results = listOfWaardeObjecten.Cast<WaardeObjecten>().ToList();

var uniqueItems = results.Where((c, i) => i != obj.getIndex());` then use `uniqueItems` to write textfile.

Comment: How do i iterate over var uniqueItems when its local? I'm writing from another class.

Comment: Like this writeLogFile(uniqueItems);? What do i put as parameter in the method of writeLogFile? private void writeLogFile(What to put here?) Sorry I barely use list and I never use "var".

Comment: @Niels : `writeLogFile(List<WaardeObjecten> items)`

Comment: Now I'm getting the following error: "Cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.Ienumerable<AddMetadataToDocuments.WaardeObjecten>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AddMetadataToDocuments.WaardeObjecten>'"

Comment: Also why we use this: "var results = listOfWaardeObjecten.Cast<WaardeObjecten>().ToList();"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157372/discussion-between-niels-and-amit-kumar).

Comment: In your last comment, use `.ToArray()` instead of `.ToList()`, thats because IEnumerable cant be converted into a list.